# How to get file size for Huge file(10GB) in c++?

Tags: c++, file, winapi, size, desktop-application

I tried to get file size for 16 GB txt file.
but I got different size with real size.
who can help me?

```
HANDLE FileHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
long long FileSize;
FileHandle = CreateFileA(szInputFileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);
if(FileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return;

FileSize = GetFileSize(FileHandle, NULL);
```

Comment: Read docs of GetFileSize, those explain why you should use its second parameter, not set it NULL.

Answer (score 7):

As you can see in the [**`GetFileSize`** documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesize):
If the file size exceeds 32bit, you must provide the 2nd argument, to be filled with the 32 high bits of the size.
Then you can combine the 2 in order to get the final file size.

Code example:

```
HANDLE FileHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
// ... (initialize FileHandle)

DWORD FileSizeLow;
DWORD FileSizeHigh;
//------------------------------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvv-
FileSizeLow = GetFileSize(FileHandle, &FileSizeHigh);
// Handle error case (see documentation link above) ...
uint64_t FileSize = ((uint64_t)FileSizeHigh << 32) + FileSizeLow;
// ...
```

---

Alternatively, as @IInspectable commented, you can use [**`GetFileSizeEx`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex):

```
LARGE_INTEGER FileSizeL;
if (GetFileSizeEx(FileHandle, &FileSizeL))
{
    LONGLONG FileSize = FileSizeL.QuadPart;  // 64bit signed
    // ...
}
else
{
    // Handle error ...
}
```

**Note:** Using `GetFileSizeEx` is actually the recomended way (the documentation above mentions it explicitly) thanks to a 64bit single result and easier error handling.

Comment: Or use [`GetFileSizeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex) and have the system do the arithmetic for you. Added bonus: This API reports errors in a natural an unsurprising way.

Answer (score 4):

The `GetFileSize` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesize) recommends using [`GetFileSizeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex) instead which is simpler:

```
LARGE_INTEGER FileSize;
if (!GetFileSizeEx(FileHandle, &FileSize))
{
  std::cout << "error getting file size\n";
}
else
{
  std::cout << "file size: " << FileSize.QuadPart << "\n";
}
```

for a more c++ solution [`std::filesystem::file_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size) (though this only works with a path, not a handle):

```
auto FileSize = std::filesystem::file_size(szInputFileName)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't really need an open `HANDLE` to the actual file itself, you can instead use `FindFirstFile()` or `GetFileAttributesEx()` to query the file size from the filesystem, eg:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
HANDLE FindHandle = FindFirstFile(szInputFileName, &fd);
if (FindHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return;
FindClose(FindHandle);

ULONGLONG FileSize = (static_cast<ULONGLONG>(fd.nFileSizeHigh) << 32) + fd.nFileSizeLow;
```

```
WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA fad;
if (!GetFileAttributesEx(szInputFileName, GetFileExInfoStandard, &fad))
    return;

ULONGLONG FileSize = (static_cast<ULONGLONG>(fad.nFileSizeHigh) << 32) + fad.nFileSizeLow;
```